# Why are rows in temp table not showing in count?

Tags: t-sql, count, temp-tables

I have a T-SQL query with temporary tables which is running and showing the count of rows per table however for one of the temp tables (which has 124 rows) the SELECT COUNT is showing as a zero and not the 124 that are in the temporary table.

I have tried changing the joins in the select statement and retyping the entire query.  I have added aliases for all the fields and double checked that all of the temporary tables are giving the correct results.  As far as I can see I have written the COUNT the same way for all 4 of the temporary tables but the COUNT(#ML.MembershipID) is the only one that is showing as a zero and not matching the row count.

--this is the select part of my query

```
SELECT #Type.MembershipType,
COUNT(#MS.MembershipID) AS MembersStartCount,
COUNT(#ME.MembershipID) AS MembersEndCount,
COUNT(#ML.MembershipID) AS MembersLostCount,
COUNT(#MN.MembershipID) AS MembersGainedCount
FROM Filteredccx_Membership mem INNER JOIN #Type ON mem.ccx_membershipid=#Type.MembershipID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #MS ON mem.ccx_membershipid=#MS.MembershipID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ME ON mem.ccx_membershipid=#ME.MembershipID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #MN ON mem.ccx_membershipid=#MN.MembershipID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ML ON mem.ccx_membershipid=#ML.MembershipID
GROUP BY #type.MembershipType
```

The COUNT(#ML.MembershipID) AS MembersLostCount, should be showing the 124 in total across the 2 membership types but it is showing 0 in both rows.  All of the other COUNT's are showing the number of rows in the temp tables.

Comment: Because its Null result... you should check joins... use isnull function and left outer join in joins... try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LEFT OUTER JOIN is probably not returning anything from the #ML table.
Meaning that #ML.MembershipID is NULL for all rows.

Try changing it to:

```
COUNT(ISNULL(#ML.MembershipID, 0)) AS MembersLostCount,
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to compare apples with pears but hadn't realised it.  There were no rows with the same id in the 2 groups when there should have been.  Have updated my query.  Thank you for the help